# Dual Boot (Bootloader Problem) UEFI, Windows 10 and Ubuntu GNOME

Tags: dual-boot, windows, bootloader, windows-10, ubuntu-gnome

So I have this HP-Pavilion from 2013 here.
I want to Install Ubuntu GNOME alongside Windows but whenever I power on my Laptop windows starts and no grub is here.

I only can boot into grub with BIOS boot Options, the Boot order has no ubuntu entry.

I tried installing with something else method and with "Install alongside Windows Bootmanager"

But both options went to default booting into windows, **I want grub to boot by default**

*Infos:
Installed both in UEFI, GPT Partition Table
Boot on /dev/sda2
Windows on /dev/sda4
Linux on /dev/sda6*

Comment: HP violates UEFI spec and you have to do a work around. Most copy /EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi to /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi. Boot-Repair will do that copy with 'use standard efi file' setting. If you have UEFI boot entry for hard drive or fallback then you should be able to boot that. Or may need to add an " UEFI Hard Drive" entry. Other alternatives & details: http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried boot-repair? Google boot-repair. You can download a bootable  ISO image that you can load to a CD or USB drive. This can fix grub for you. Be sure to look at the online suggestions.

http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/

Comment: Nice suggestion but I don't have a broken bootloader, grub just does not show up and windows boots by deafult what I don't want